# Custom Taxonomy causing max execution error when logged in

Tags: php, wordpress

Perhaps I have been looking at this code so long that the error is obvious and I am just missing it.  I created a custom Taxonomy ('tutorial_passes') but for some strange reason whenever I am logged in as a non admin user any page visited on my site will sit there and eventually end with a Max Execution (30 sec) error appears.  If I comment the load that runs the register_taxonomy function then all is fine.

Here is my code for the custom Taxonomy....

```
function cptui_register_my_taxes_tutorial_passes() {

/**
 * Taxonomy: Tutorial Passes.
 */

$labels = array(
    "name" => __( 'Tutorial Passes', 'streamworksaudio-audio' ),
    "singular_name" => __( 'Tutorial Pass', 'streamworksaudio-audio' ),
    "add_new_item" => __( 'Add New Tutorial Pass', 'streamworksaudio-audio' ),
);

$args = array(
    "label" => __( 'Tutorial Passes', 'streamworksaudio-audio' ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "public" => true,
    "hierarchical" => false,
    "label" => "Tutorial Passes",
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
    "query_var" => true,
    "rewrite" => array( 'slug' => 'tutorial_passes', 'with_front' => true, ),
    "show_admin_column" => false,
    "show_in_rest" => false,
    "rest_base" => "",
    "show_in_quick_edit" => false,
);
register_taxonomy( "tutorial_passes", array( "media_downloads" ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_taxes_tutorial_passes' );
```

Again, maybe I am unable to see the error... but it looks good to me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it has something to do with WooCommerce Memberships extension.  I had custom taxes that were being used by the plugin. As soon as I removed then from WooCommerce Memberships the issue went away.